# Calling cmake with bash variable argument

Tags: bash, shell, cmake, arguments

I am struggling into an odd issue. I am trying to run cmake command line with a shell variable as an argument but it fails. This is what I've done:

```
#1. Basic. works fine
cmake -G 'Sublime Text 2 - Ninja'

#2. Argument into variable. error
CMAKE_CONFIG="-G 'Sublime Text 2 - Ninja'"
cmake $CMAKE_CONFIG ../..
> CMake Error: Could not create named generator  'Sublime Text 2 - Ninja'

#3. Adding -v before variable. 'compile' but ignore the argument (generate a Makefile). Hacky and senseless?
CMAKE_CONFIG="-G 'Sublime Text 2 - Ninja'"
cmake -v$CMAKE_CONFIG ../..

#4. Quoting argument. error (same as #2)
CMAKE_CONFIG="-G 'Sublime Text 2 - Ninja'"
cmake "$CMAKE_CONFIG" ../..
```

Playing with --trace and --debug-output variables gives the following:

```
#5. Working command
cmake ../.. --trace --debug-output -G "Sublime Text 2 - Ninja"

#6. Non existing generator. 
#Expected result (witness purpose only)
cmake ../.. --trace --debug-output -G 'random test'     
[...]
CMake Error: Could not create named generator random test

#7. Testing with variable. 
#Output error quotes the generator's name and there is an extra space before it
cmake ../.. --trace --debug-output $CMAKE_CONFIG     
[...]
CMake Error: Could not create named generator  'Sublime Text 2 - Ninja'

#8. Removing the quote within the variable. 
#Still error, but the only difference with #6 is the extra space after 'generator'
CMAKE_CONFIG="-G Sublime Text 2 - Ninja"
cmake ../.. --trace --debug-output $CMAKE_CONFIG     
[...]
CMake Error: Could not create named generator  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja
```

I tried to change the IFS variable too but didn't succeed to achieve my goal.

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you need to debug the shell, not `cmake`. The trick is to replace "cmake" by `printf '%q\n'` in your commands, to let `bash` show you how it interprets your arguments.

I think using arrays like this will work:

```
CMAKE_CONFIG=(-G 'Sublime Text 2 - Ninja')
cmake "${CMAKE_CONFIG[@]}" ../..
```

Comment: Correct. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more details.

Comment: @Martin Vidner you saved my day! Thanks a lot! I didn't know trivial things can be complex some times